# I am running a large number of SELECT queries at once and it takes seconds to run. Why isn't it quicker due to MySQL caching?

Tags: mysql, caching

I have a table with 70 rows. For learning/testing purposes I wrote out a query for each row. So I wrote:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id="id1";
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id="id2";
/*etc*/
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id="id70";
```

And ran it in Sequel Pro. All of the queries took a total of 5 seconds. This seems like a really long time since I had read that MySQL has a feature called [The MySQL Query Cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html). It seems like a query cache, if it is this slow, is pretty useless and I might as well write my own layer of query caching between the database layer and the frontend.

Is it correct that the MySQL query cache is this slow? Or do I need to activate something or fix something to get it to work?

Comment: before tweaking cache I'd look for an index on the id column.

Answer (score 2):

Per the cache documentation, it maps the text of a select statement to the returned result. Since all of those are different, the result wouldn't be cached until they have all been executed once. Does it take just as long the second time?

5 seconds seems slow even without the cache for a normal case though. How big is the table? Is id the primary key? If it is not the PK, then the server is reading every row, and just returning the one that met the criteria you asked for.

Edit - Since you're using a hosted solution, are you running the query from something on the host network, or across the internet? If it's across the internet, then the problem is almost certainly network latency rather than execution time. Especially running the queries individually, since you'll incur transit time for each select.

Comment: Yes, it takes the same amount of time each time. More than 4 seconds (I rounded up to 5). The id is the primary key. It's a string, not a number with auto increment (if that matters).

Comment: If you have only 70 rows it should not matter what kind of key you have. There is something terribly wrong either on the server itself, in between you and the server, or with your client machine. You need to debug it on the system level.

Comment: I'm using Dreamhost. I guess I can try another server?

Answer (score 0):

If you query just based on primary key, you might as well use the memcached interface.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-memcached.html

Comment: Cool---will check it out. I'm looking for a deeper explanation why the built in MySQL query cache doesn't work.

Comment: Query cache is not that great. Some shops don't activate it. For high loads, innodb would be more powerful.

Comment: What do you mean by "shops"? And I am using innodb.

Comment: Some companies. Facebook is known to not use query cache. Certainly they have their own way of doing cache. There is a big lock on mysql query cache that won't scale to a certain point (think concurrent access).